# Remove canvas element on click with typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am new to typescript and what i am trying is, to remove canvas element from the div. So here is my HTML code.

```
<div class="chart">
    <canvas id="nav-chart"></canvas>
</div>
```

on click removing the canvas element using id `nav-chart`. So here my JS code inside the onclick function

```
const elem: HTMLElement = document.getElementById('nav-chart')
if (elem) {
   elem.parentElement.removeChild(elem)
}
```

While trying this it throws the error saying at the line 
`const elem: HTMLElement = document.getElementById('nav-chart')`

```
TS2322: Type 'HTMLElement | null' is not assignable to type 'HTMLElement'.
  Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'HTMLElement'.
```

and in this line `elem.parentElement.removeChild(elem)`

```
TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution first we have to declare the element type with `HTMLElement | null`

```
const elem: HTMLElement | null = document.getElementById('nav-chart')
```

and inside the condition.

```
if (elem) {
      elem.parentElement && elem.parentElement.removeChild(elem)
}
```